# Saving result of celery group task in django database using TaskSetMeta model

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm creating group of tasks and adding them to a queue.

```
def process(self, request, queryset):
    tasks = group([
        mytask.s(user_id=obj.id)
        for obj in list(queryset)
    ])
    result = tasks.applay_async()
```

Results of each separate task are saved in django database in model TaskMeta according to settings:

```
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
```

However, I can't see any new rows for model TaskSetMeta.

Is this model designed to work only with `celery.task.sets.TaskSet` object, which is currently deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In django-celery does not automaticlly save result of group() and `TaskSetMeta` as it is in case of single task and `TaskMeta`. To create record in `TaskSetMeta` for creating group tasks you have to call `.save()` at the end:

```
def process(self, request, queryset):
    tasks = group([
        mytask.s(user_id=obj.id)
        for obj in list(queryset)
    ])
    result = tasks.apply_async()
    result.save()
```

Comment: This won't work with `django-celery-results`, as it throws `AttributeError: 'DatabaseBackend' object has no attribute '_save_group'`. And here is the reference to this issue. https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results/issues/40

Comment: @VineethSai, Have you found a solution to save the group task? I am trying to save chunked task but it is having the _save_group issues that you mentioned. If you have any idea, please let me know.